# can i send firebase verification email from another email provider?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, salesforce

I'm creating an app with node.js and i'm using Firebase authentication.

After the user sign up, I want to send the verification email through Salesforce API. How can I make Firebase do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom SMTP server for sending emails in the Firebase console.

1. Go to the [Authentication panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication) in the Firebase console
2. Click on the [Templates tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/emails)
3. Click on <kbd>SMTP settings</kbd>
4. Click the <kbd>Enable</kbd> toggle to enable the custom SMTP server settings
5. Fill out the details of your SMTP server and click <kbd>Save</kbd>

[image]